# XML Management Inteface in Datapower thorwing an error

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

When connecting to XML Manager Interface getting "Access denied" error.

```
<dp:url-open target="http://host:port/service/mgmt/current" response="responsecode">
</dp:url-open>
```

Returning response code 5 and reason being Access denied.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure that your xml management is open on http and not https?? I've certainly never seen this. You have to pass credentials of a user who is allowed to perform the action you need via xml management.

Comment: How can I check , whether the user is having an access or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After passing the Auth header , am able to access XML management interface.